# JQuery on("click") no funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una classe llamada Juego, que contiene su constructor, atributos y sus métodos. Tengo un método que lo hace es controlar el click normal y el clickderecho para poder jugar. El clcik normal lo que hace es descubrir lo que hay en la casilla y si hay una bomba pierdes... El derecho lo que hace es poner y quitar la bandera y lo que hago para controlar que el jugar no pueda hacer click encima de donde hay una bandera, pues desactivo el evento click sobre esa casilla, y si el jugador más tarde quita la bandera lo que hago es reactivar el clik. Pero a la hora de reactivar el click no funciona y no se puede hacer click otra vez.
Mi codigo es elsiguiente:

```
Class Juego {
//aquí los atributos que tengo 
//aquí están los métodos 

}
```

Luego mas abajo tengo un ready, y cuando se ha cargado toda la pagina lo que hago es poder iniciar el juego:

```
partida = new Joc(); //joc == juego

$(botonIniciar).click(function(){
    if(!partida.genereadoCasillas()){
        partida.tablero.crear();partida.iniciarJuego()
        partida.calcularNumeros();
        Escucha();
    }
})

$(botonParar).click(function(){
    partida.pararJuego()
})

$(botonReiniciar).click(function(){
    partida.reiniciarJuego();
})


function Escucha(){ 
    espia=partida.espiaJuego()
    for (i=0; i< espia.length; i++){


        $(espia[i]).click(function(event){ //Aquí controlo el click y llama al método para poder comprobar si hay bomba o no y mostrar lo que toque.
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("Fuera de la clase " + this.id)
            if(parseInt(this.id,10)>=0){
                console.log("Dentro de la clase " + this.id)
                partida.clickCasilla(parseInt(this.id,10));
            }
            return false;
        })
        $(espia[i]).contextmenu(function(event){ //Aqui llamo al método del clcik derecho para poner la bandera o quitarla
            if(parseInt(this.id,10)>=0){
                partida.rClickCasilla(parseInt(this.id,10),event);
            }
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        })
    }
}
```

Lo métodos a los que llamo están dentro de la clase juego:

```
    Class Juego {
    //aquí los atributos que tengo 
    //aquí están los métodos 
    clickCasilla (espia){ 
            console.log(espia)
            if(this.empezadoJuego()){             //Si se ha empezado el juego se hacen las comprobaciones
                if(this.tablero.dibujar()[espia].descobrir() == -1){
                    console.log("BOMBA");
                    alert("Has perdido le has dado a la bomba")
                    $(this.espiaJuego()[espia+2]).css("background","transparent");
                    $(this.espiaJuego()[espia+2]).css("backgroundImage","url('./mina.gif.')");
                    $(this.espiaJuego()[espia+2]).off("click");
                    $(this.espiaJuego()[espia+2]).off("contextmenu");
                    this.pararJuego();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $("div#tablerominas").children().each(function(){
                            $(this).fadeOut(200);})
                    },2500)
                }else{
                    $(this.espiaJuego()[espia+2]).css("background","transparent");
                    console.log(this.tablero.dibujar()[espia].descobrir())
                    $(this.espiaJuego()[espia+2]).html(this.tablero.dibujar()[espia].descobrir())
                    console.log("valor del contenido "+this.tablero.dibujar()[espia].descobrir())
                    $(this.espiaJuego()[espia+2]).off("click");
                    $(this.espiaJuego()[espia+2]).off("contextmenu");
                }
            }
        }
        rClickCasilla (espia,eve){
            if(this.empezadoJuego()){    //Si se ha empezado el juego se hacen las comprobaciones
                console.log("vigilando bandera");
                console.log("Posiciones bombas --->"+this.tablero.saberPsoiBombas())
                if(this.contadorbanderas.sNumBanderes()>=1 && this.contadorbanderas.registadaPosi(espia)==false){
                    this.contadorbanderas.decrementar();
                    console.log("dentro de rclick --->" +espia);
                    this.contadorbanderas.anadirPosi(espia);
                    $("#cbanderas").html(this.contadorbanderas.sNumBanderes());
                    $(this.espiaJuego()[espia+2]).css("background","transparent");
                    $(this.espiaJuego()[espia+2]).css("background-image","url(flag.png)");
                    $(this.espiaJuego()[espia+2]).off("click");  // desactivo sobre el objeto el evento clikc
                }else if(this.contadorbanderas.sNumBanderes()>=1 && this.contadorbanderas.registadaPosi(espia)==true){
                    this.contadorbanderas.borrarPosi(espia);
                    this.contadorbanderas.incrementar();
                    $("#cbanderas").html(this.contadorbanderas.sNumBanderes());
                    $(this.espiaJuego()[espia+2]).css({ 'background' : '', 'opacity' : '' });
                    console.log("ID DENTRO DE LCICKD--->"+$(this.espiaJuego()[espia+2]).attr('id'));
                    $(this.espiaJuego()[espia+2]).on("click",eve); //aqui lo vuelvo a activar, Y ESTO ES NO LO QUE NO FUNCCIONA 
                    console.log("botonazo");
                }
                if(this.contadorbanderas.sNumBanderes()==0){
                    console.log("asdasdasd");
                    if (JSON.stringify(this.contadorbanderas.sPosiBanderas()) === JSON.stringify(this.tablero.saberPsoiBombas())) {
                        alert("HAS GANADO !!!");
                        this.pararJuego();
                    }else{
                        alert("asdasd");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Alguien sabe porque no se reactiva el evento click? GRACIAS!!

Comment: ¿Has mirado en consola si te sale algún mensaje de error?

Comment: @Triby El eve es la referencia del evento pasándosela por el método

Comment: @NicolasOñate En la consola no sale ningún error

Comment: @Triby He estado haciendo pruebas con el evento para ver si podia hacer algo, pero no funciona y lo tengo por ahi escrito lo puedes ignorar pero al hacer el console log del eve es el Objeto

Comment: ¿Qué objeto? Podría ser la clase, una función (o método), evento, etc.

Comment: @Triby el objeto que se obtiene es un div son sus parámetros y claro lo que hago es desactivar el click o activarlo

Comment: El parámetro para asignar evento debe ser una función y no un objeto (o div).

Comment: @Triby tiene que ser el objeto al cual quiero dar el evnto click te dejo el link donde tengo este proyect

Comment: @Triby aqui tienes el link para que hagas la prueba http://mohamedinsjoaquimmicar.rf.gd/A12v1/buscaminas.html si pones una bandera al quitarla ya no se le asigna el clikc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo evitaría asignar, eliminar y volver a asignar eventos, porque facilita mucho las cosas, por ejemplo:

**Analizar valores antes de realizar la acción:**

No acabo de entender tu código, así que la sugerencia es para adaptar, realizando las comparaciones con los métodos de tu clase o valores de cada elemento.

```
function clicNormal() {
    // Ya inició el juego?
    if(this.empezadoJuego()) {
        // No tiene bandera y todavía no ha recibido clic?
        if(!this.tieneBandera() && !this.descubierto()) {
            if(this.tieneBomba()) {
                // Parar el juego, this.empezadoJuego() debe devolver falso
                // para ignorar cualquier clic posterior
            }
            // No tiene bomba
        }
    }
}
function clicDerecho() {
    // Ya inició el juego?
    if(this.empezadoJuego()) {
        // Tiene bandera?
        if(this.tieneBandera()) {
            // Simplemente quitas la bandera
        } else if(!this.tieneBandera() && !this.descubierto()) {
            // No tiene bandera y no ha recibido clic
            // Colocar bandera
        }
    }
}
```

Con esos pequeños cambios, no es necesario eliminar eventos, porque los siguientes clics serán ignorados.

Si aún quieres eliminar y volver a asignar eventos, hay que cambiar la forma en que asignas los eventos y obtienes el elemento:

```
$(this.espiaJuego()[espia+2]).on("click", function(event) {
    this.clickCasilla(espia, event);
});
$(this.espiaJuego()[espia+2]).contextmenu(function(event) {
    this.rClickCasilla(espia, event);
});
```

No me queda claro porqué usar `espia+2` como índice, pero si es el elemento adecuado, entonces debes asegurarte de que estás creando nuevamente los eventos con los métodos y parámetros que corresponden.

**Nota:** En el juego tienes un posible error, porque después de perder hice un clic en otro recuadro y se realizaron acciones; creo que se debería detener todo el juego y escuchar solo lo que pasa con los botones.

Answer (score 0):

Para trabajar con `jQuery` necesitas los `id` de los elementos. Es decir si tienes botones debes tener algo así:

```
<input type="button" name="botonIniciar" id="botonIniciar">
```

Ahora para el evento `click` de ese botón sería:

```
$("#botonIniciar").click(function(){
    //Tu código
});
```

Comment: si ya tiene ID con son numéricos, en un método de otra clase se generan de forma dinamica los divs